# How to delete only the table rows' last tds/columns?

Tags: javascript

The idea is to be able to delete the table rows' last column, containing the header Sel. and the checkboxes. The function deletes everything, including the table footer rows' cells, which is where the total is and that value is then lost.

The function runs when the user clicks print and it uses `window.print()`, but the table misses the total visually.

```js
const allRows = document.getElementById("dtable").rows;
for (let i = allRows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
}
```

```html
<html>



<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
</head>
<table class="table table-hover table-vcenter" id="dtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:5%">Yards</th>
      <th style="width:8%">Total FOB</th>
      <th style="width:4%">Sel.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableRows">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this); deposit(term())"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" class="qty" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="add_to_total(this); deposit(term())"></td>
      <td class="total_price"><strong>$0.00</strong></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td id="totalTitle" colspan="2" align="right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
      <td id="totalValue" class="total">$0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="termsRow" colspan="1" align="right"><strong>Deposit(%):</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="term" min="0" class="terms" name="numberInputs" value="" onchange="deposit(this)"></td>
      <td id="termsTotal" class="total_terms"><strong></strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

</html>
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of starting with the last row, start with the 3rd from last row:

```
for (let i = allRows.length - 3; i > 0; i--) { // 3, not 1!
```

Comment: My lack of experience looking forward is already limited....imagine looking at solutions backwards process wise. It works! Thanks!